Color change in package pst-labo
I would like to add other glassware fill color in the package.
I tested this code to get orange color in the test tube but it doesn't work
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pst-labo}
\newpsstyle{FerIII}{linestyle=none, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=OrangePale}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(5,6)
\rput(3,3.7){\pstTubeEssais[niveauLiquide1=25,aspectLiquide1=ferIII]}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}


Your FerIII and ferIII are different. So, for example
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pst-labo}
\newpsstyle{FerIII}{linestyle=none, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=OrangePale}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(5,6)
\rput(3,3.7){\pstTubeEssais[niveauLiquide1=25,aspectLiquide1=FerIII]}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}


